# Callback from Angularjs factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-factory

I want to get a callback from a factory. If I understand correctly, the callback should be in the deepest nested function (i.e. under `var myResult = $filter('filter')(myData, {id:exnum})[0];`, but I get "TypeError: callback is not a function".

My factory calls another factory, gets a value and injects it into a third one for the final result. This final result logs correctly to console, but I cannot callback to the controller.

Any feedback would be appreciated.

```
angular.module('resourceFetch', [])
.factory('ResourceFetch', ['JsonService', 'UserProgress', '$filter', function(JsonService, UserProgress, $filter) {

    var resourceResult = {};
    resourceResult.getResource = function(callback){

      UserProgress.getProgress(function(exnum, callback) {
        JsonService.get(function(data){
        var myData = [];
        var myData = data.exercises;
        var myResult = [];
        var myResult = $filter('filter')(myData, {id:exnum})[0];
        console.log(myResult) // <- this displays correctly
        callback(myResult); // <- "TypeError: callback is not a function"
        });
     });
   //callback(myResult); <- here "myResult is not defined"
   };
    return resourceResult;
}]);
```

This is the controller:

```
myApp.controller('ResourceFetchTest', function($scope, ResourceFetch) {

    $scope.myresults = ResourceFetch.getResource(function(obj1){
       console.log('obj1 is ' + obj1);
       $scope.MyData = obj1;
       $scope.MySelectedData = obj1.string1;
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a promise to return the object

Something like:

```
angular.module('resourceFetch', [])
.factory('ResourceFetch', ['JsonService', 'UserProgress', '$filter','$q', function(JsonService, UserProgress, $filter,$q) {

    var resourceResult = {};
    resourceResult.getResource = function(){
    var defer = $q.defer();
      UserProgress.getProgress(function(exnum) {
        JsonService.get(function(data){
        var myData = [];
        var myData = data.exercises;
        var myResult = [];
        var myResult = $filter('filter')(myData, {id:exnum})[0];
        console.log(myResult) // <- this displays correctly
        defer.resolve(myResult); 
        });
     });
   return defer.promise;
   };
    return resourceResult;
}]);
```

and in the controller:

```
myApp.controller('ResourceFetchTest', function($scope, ResourceFetch) {

    $scope.myresults = ResourceFetch.getResource().then(function(obj1){
       console.log('obj1 is ' + obj1);
       $scope.MyData = obj1;
       $scope.MySelectedData = obj1.string1;
    }); 
});
```

here's the documentation on promises:https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Let me know if you have questions I had the simular problem today and fixed it this way

Comment: Thank you, using $q was indeed much easier than regular callbacks. My only issue is you need to return the main function at the end and return defer.promise from within it. It worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my previous answer was not looking at your code properly, your biggest issue here is that you are trying to pass services within services and it makes your code hard to follow.

What you should do is inject all of your services to your controller module and then you can do something along the lines of this.

```
myApp.controller('ResourceFetchTest', function($scope, ResourceFetch) {

    $scope.dataForProgress = "Bind whatever data in needed to get your progress";

    $scope.dataForJson = UserProgress.getProgress(dataForProgress);

    $scope.myResults = JsonService.get(dataForJson);

});
```

Depending on what each service does and what it calls it is possible you are also making Async calls in which case I would recommend looking into the $q directive angular provides.

Comment: I'm sorry, reference resourceResult as vm.resourceResult where?

Comment: I'm on my phone right now but I'll post a more in depth answer in about 20 minutes.